# Run a function after an ajax looped get completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to get arrays of points for a googlemap, it works fine apart from I need to call the MarkerClusterer after the final `$.get` has completed.

If I just place the code after the for loop then it runs before the queued gets have completed and doesn't work correctly.

If I used a callback on the `$.get` then it will run on each loop which is not what I want either

**The code**

```
for (i = 1; i <= <?=$pages;?>; i++) {

    points = [];

    $.get("/mappoints/" + i + "/true", function(data) {

        $.each(data.json_array, function(index, value){

            //do things with data
        });
    }, "json");         
}

//run this code after the queued `$.get`s have **all** completed
console.log("done");
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

I've tried the following within the `for` but that didn't even run, not too sure why?

```
if(i == <?=$pages;?>){
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    console.log("done");
}
```

Comment: You need to look into promises

Comment: For making a callback on a series of async calls, check out the library async.js https://github.com/caolan/async What I don't see is why you would page the requests and then call them all in serie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply keep track of how many have completed, and when they've all completed, run your code. Also, don't forget to `var` your variables to prevent global leakage.

```
var points, counter = 0, i;
for (i = 1; i <= <?=$pages;?>; i++) {
    points = [];

    $.get("/mappoints/" + i + "/true", function(data) {

        $.each(data.json_array, function(index, value){

            //do things with data

        });
        counter++;
        if (counter === <?=$pages;?>) {
            console.log("done");
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }
    }, "json");

}
```

A better alternative may be to collect an array of promises and apply them to `$.when()`.

```
var points, promises =  [], i;
for (i = 1; i <= <?=$pages;?>; i++) {
    points = [];

    promises.push($.get("/mappoints/" + i + "/true", function(data) {

        $.each(data.json_array, function(index, value){

            //do things with data

        });

    }, "json"));

}
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function () {
    console.log("done");
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
});
```

Comment: I'm using your second example but the `console.log("done")` is never output so I don't think it's getting there?

Comment: Are all the requests successful? If any one of them fail, you'll instead need a .fail callback to see why.

Comment: There's two logs for each `$.get`, one is successful and the data is returned but the other says xhr cancelled?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't caused by `//do things with data`? the code in my answer should only be sending one request per iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Use $.when and .then

```
$.when(
// Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

// Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

// Deferred object (probably Ajax request)

).then(function() {

// All have been resolved (or rejected), do your thing

});
```

Comment: Trying to use a for inside the when but it says unexpected token?

Comment: @Silver89 you can't use a for loop in place of an argument list.

Comment: What do you mean? In the $.when, you pass the $.get(yourlink)'s comma separated, without callback handler.